# jest-Puppeteer does not see alias path defined in moduleNameMapper

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, tdd, puppeteer

When trying to run tests with **jest-puppeteer**, jest does not see alias path.
Example:

```
import ROUTER_NAMES from "@/app/auth/core/router-const"

// got error
Cannot find module '@/app/auth/core/router-const' from 'middleware-auth.js'
```

In jest.config.js i defined moduleNameMapper

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$'": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    ...
```

All okay when i running default jest unit tests, but not with jest-puppeteer. 
How to fix this problem?

Comment: Very likely you have not added the [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) mechanics.